# What to do when reviewing the post without radio option?

Tags: discussion, review

I recently reviewed the [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90026/product-inquiry-form-in-ubercart) for low quality, but when reviewing it have no radio option to select, see the below screenshot. Note I think I already flagged that post, but I'm not sure about the reason(probably "unclear what you are asking"). Like this situation what should I do ? or Is this bug?

> [image]

Later: (Since it have no option I clicked the Looks good button)

Comment: Look at the bottom of the dialog. And don't click looks good if it deserved a close, skip if you can't (or don't want to) act.

Comment: @Mat Yes I know the message at the bottom. I done this same thing for first post or late answer review, but It have the I'm Done button enabled by default, when I already made any edits etc.., But this one looks different, right ?

Comment: @CRUSADER I understand It looks similar, but it don't have answer

Comment: @Bala Yes, it was a feature request to show a dialog with msg "You have already flagged this post" rather than this screen with no select-able radio-button.. Moreover, there wasnt any message at bottom before.. seems to be added now... :)

Comment: @CRUSADER slight difference between this two is, my post describes during review and the other one is when flagging, I doubt message at the bottom shows for both criteria